# Restart cnosdb, panic

Tags: database, time-series, cnosdb

Restart cnosdb, panic

version:cnosdb 2.3.0, revision = 954d3b6f581e74b520f4a964700832cf39545b20

I am monitoring the environment, restarting the cnosdb single node, process panic

the logs as follow:

```
2023-11-27T09:48:22.725486421Z  INFO meta::store::state_machine: METADATA WRITE: /cluster_xxx/data_nodes_metrics/1001 :{"id":1001,"disk_free":186444648448,"time":1701078502,"status":"Healthy"}
2023-11-27T09:48:29.986295017Z  INFO tskv::index::ts_index: index recover file: "/var/lib/cnosdb/db/data/cnosdb.cadvisor/9/index/_000001.binlog"
The application panicked (crashed).
Message:  called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: IndexErr { source: DecodeSeriesKey { msg: "Invalid serde message: Invalid serde message: io error: unexpected end of file" } }
Location: /cnosdb/tskv/src/kvcore.rs:176

  ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ BACKTRACE ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
                                ⋮ 9 frames hidden ⋮                               
  10: tskv::kvcore::TsKv::open::{{closure}}::he66de7f933eb3383
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  11: cnosdb::server::ServiceBuilder::create_tskv::{{closure}}::hd33f8c2f32b085da
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  12: cnosdb::server::ServiceBuilder::build_query_storage::{{closure}}::h35477718c967f2e6
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  13: cnosdb::main::{{closure}}::h08f1d55c5bb830f5
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  14: cnosdb::main::h7e8535668f31b027
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
```